# ReferenceError: drag is not defined in custom drag and drop

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I wrote a code for simple drag and drop editor. It has 3 panels, I drag an item from first panel to second panel and contents of dragged item appear in 3rd panel. Code is in: https://jsfiddle.net/tek0rfsw/
Full screen result is in: http://jsfiddle.net/tek0rfsw/embedded/result/
**javaScript code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#remittanceId').hide();
  $('#goldId').hide();

  //alert("caling");
  /* 
  var $this = $(this);


    alert("caling2222");
    $("#remittanceId").css("display", "");
      $("#remittanceId").css("display", "block"); */

});

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);

  //alert($('#drag1').text());
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

  // var id = $('#drag1').text();

  var value = $(ev).text();
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var id = $('#' + data).text().replace(/\s/g, '');

  //alert(id);
  /* if (id == "1)Remittence") {
     alert('remitt'); 
     var remHead = $('#remId').text().replace(/\s/g, '');
    document.getElementById("featureHead").innerHTML = remHead;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'row';
    div.innerHTML = '<div class="container"><select name="dropdown" class="selectpicker" id="fromCurrencyId"><option value="0" selected>Select From Currency</option><!-- <option value="MYR">MYR-</option> --><option value="MYR">AED-DIRHAM</option><option value="USD">USD-US DOLLAR</option></select> &#8594; <select name="dropdown" class="selectpicker" id="toCurrencyId" onchange="checkFromCurrency()"><option value="0" selected>Select To Currency</option><option value="INR">INR-INDIAN RUPEE</option></select> <br><br> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Clear" onclick="remittanceClear()" /> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" onclick="remittanceSave()" /></div>';
    document.getElementById('featureBody').appendChild(div);
    return 0; 
  } */
  if (id == "2)AssetGold") {
    //alert('sdzhx');
    errorShow();
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else {
    /* error(); */
    var remHead = $('#remId').text().replace(/\s/g, '');
    document.getElementById("featureHead").innerHTML = remHead;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'row';
    div.innerHTML = '<div class="container"><select name="dropdown" class="selectpicker" id="fromCurrencyId"><option value="0" selected>Select From Currency</option><!-- <option value="MYR">MYR-</option> --><option value="MYR">AED-DIRHAM</option><option value="USD">USD-US DOLLAR</option></select> &#8594; <select name="dropdown" class="selectpicker" id="toCurrencyId" onchange="checkFromCurrency()"><option value="0" selected>Select To Currency</option><option value="INR">INR-INDIAN RUPEE</option></select> <br><br> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Clear" onclick="remittanceClear()" /> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" onclick="remittanceSave()" /></div>';
    document.getElementById('featureBody').appendChild(div);
    return false;
  }
  if (id == "3)CrudeOil") {
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
/* function show(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var newID = ev.dataTransfer.getData("id");
    alert(id);
} */

function assetClear() {
  swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, clear it!",
      closeOnConfirm: false
    },
    function() {
      swal("Cleared!", "Your imaginary file has been cleared.",
        "success");
    });
}

function remittanceClear() {
  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be to save the values!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, clear it!",
    closeOnConfirm: false
  }, function() {
    swal("Cleared!", "Your values are cleared.", "success");
  });
}

function saveAsset() {
  swal("Good!", "Asset Details Added Successfully.", "success");
}

function remittanceSave() {
  swal("Good!", "Remittance Details Added Successfully.", "success");
}

function error() {
  swal('Oops...',
    'Something went wrong! Please contact the adminisrator',
    'error');
}

function errorShow() {
  swal('Oops...', 'Not allowed. You can use one feature at a time',
    'error');
}
```

When I run the code in browser, I get this error: `ReferenceError: drag is not defined`. What am I missing?

Comment: your code is working [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/KarthikeyanVedi/tek0rfsw/1/embedded/result/)..

Comment: Oh great... In 2nd panel, only one feature is allowed. If I drag 2nd feature, it should show an alert that only one feature is working and dragged feature should go back to 1st panel. I'm able to get alert, but dragged item doesn't go back to 1st panel. How can I fix that?

Comment: can you please tell me how drag worked in your jsfiddle, but not in my jsfiddle?